# Understanding REST java server with database

Tags: java, spring, rest

Goal: Set up a java server that maintains a high-score list for java client using REST.

Programming experience: Beginner but closer to the intermediate spectrum I would hope.

I have been told last night that REST is good practice for this goal. I have been reading about it all morning into the afternoon and am getting more confused the more I read, so I figured I would ask a few basic questions to ideally get me studying in the right direction. I have run the spring hello world with success and understanding (http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) but am not sure what to do for my next step in this learning process.

I know I will need to save the high-scores and possibly other information to a database but am not sure what type of database, how to create it, and how to store and retrieve data from it.

I am also wondering about client side implementation, how to make the client send and receive the data to and from server.

I found that I am a spatial learner and learn best through examples, so relative code examples would be greatly helpful. Book recommendations are also appreciated. When I decided to learn JavaFX, someone here recommended the Pro JavaFX 8 book from apress and I found it to be a very good reference.

Thank you for taking the time to help a novice out, we all have to start somewhere. Cheers

Comment: What you need to do first is to understand what is RESTful, why it is considered as `good` practice. Having a steady foundation before building a skyscrape is always good for your future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 . Database 
It's more of your choice. To start with you can go with MySQL. You can find a lot of tutorial which can guide you how to create tables and stuff.

2. Output
   As you have decided to use restful services you can get the data from server either in xml or Json format.
3. Client side
   At the client side you can use Json parser to parse the data and use Dom (document object model) to update your webpage. Basically you can use jquery to find an id of a div section and update the html for it.

   Below is a link for restful service in spring mvc
   http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-restful-web-services-crud-example-resttemplate/

Comment: Thanks for the upvote please let me know if you need help